# How to save records in relation manytomany Django

Tags: django, django-models

Good afternoon I have my application in Django 1.10, where I create a many-to-many relationship between the Beneficiario and Auxilio models, the beneficiario field being the key to this relationship, as you can see, I needed an additional field in the model that would be created by this relationship , so customize the model Auxilio_Beneficiario with 'through', to better understand:

**models.py**

```
class Dependencia(models.Model):
    dependencia = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Beneficiario(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    numeroDocumento = models.BigIntegerField()

class Auxilio(models.Model):
    auxilio = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    dependencia = models.ForeignKey(Dependencia)
    beneficiario = models.ManyToManyField(Beneficiario, through='Auxilio_Beneficiario')

class Auxilio_Beneficiario(models.Model):
    auxilio = models.ForeignKey(Auxilio)
    beneficiario = models.ForeignKey(Beneficiario)
    fechaEntrega = models.DateField(null=True)
```

The problem that I have is that I do not know how to record the information in the model Auxilio_Beneficiario:

**views.py**

```
def asignaAuxilio(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        beneficiario = Beneficiario.objects.get(numeroDocumento=request.POST['documento'])
        #
        #
        #No se como grabar los campos auxilio,beneficiario,fecha de entrega
        #
        # 
        return render(request, 'asignaAuxilio.html')
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering how to access the `through` model, then the simplest way is to add `related_name`s to the `ForeignKey`s like that:

```
class Auxilio_Beneficiario(models.Model):
    auxilio = models.ForeignKey(Auxilio, related_name='auxilio_beneficiario')
    beneficiario = models.ForeignKey(Beneficiario, related_name='auxilio_beneficiario')
    fechaEntrega = models.DateField(null=True)
```

Now you can access it like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    beneficiario = Beneficiario.objects.get(numeroDocumento=request.POST['documento'])

    through_model = beneficiario.auxilio_beneficiario.first() # Or filter based on your system's needs
    through_model.fechaEntrega = request.POST.get('something')
    through_model.save()


    return render(request, 'asignaAuxilio.html')
```

Did I answer your question?